# find sum of series $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{i^2}}$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{i^2}}$ but have no idea how to approach it

Comment: It is a trascendental number with a nice binary representation but nothing more.

Comment: In what context do you need this number?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Is there a simple way to see why it's transcendental?  That isn't obvious to me.

Comment: @rVitale: no, trascendence is not trivial. It follows from the improved version of the trascendence proof for the Liouville constant (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number). Irrationality, however, is quite straighforward.

Answer (score 1):

Recalling the Jacobi theta 3 function is $$\theta_{3}\left(q\right)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}q^{n^{2}}
 $$ and the indentity $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}q^{n^{2}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\theta_{3}\left(q\right)+1\right)
 $$ we have $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n^{2}}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\theta_{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+1\right).
 $$